# PowerManager.WakeLock inactive when power button pressed

Tags: android

I am using a PowerManager.WakeLock to keep the device from going to sleep automatically during certain states of my app.  However, if the user presses the power button, I want the device to power off.  Is there a WakeLock flag that can do this?  Or is there a notification I can receive when the user presses the power button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a WakeLock flag that can do this?

Any `WakeLock` type other than `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` will have this effect. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html):

> If you hold a partial wakelock, the CPU will continue to run, irrespective of any timers and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wakelocks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button.

You should only hold a partial `WakeLock` for background work that you want to run to completion (e.g., long file download), then release that `WakeLock`.

> Or is there a notification I can receive when the user presses the power button?

No sorry.

Comment: Thank you.  I re-read the documentation and reviewed my code.  Your explanation helped me see what my problem was.  I actually was using SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | ON_AFTER_RELEASE.  I was releasing the wake lock when my activity was paused.  This occurred when the power button was pressed.  Then because ON_AFTER_RELEASE was being used, the screen would immediately power back on.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, which will come in nifty if you’re making an application that might need to save state or respond to the user’s screen going to sleep/waking up, etc.